# why I am getting "generic parameter could not be inferred" , generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I'm learning generic type + protocol by creating some foods which conform a protocol named `Nutrition`

```
protocol Nutrition {
        var calories: Double { get set }
        var price: Double { get set }
    }

    struct Hamburger: Nutrition {
        var calories    =   100.0
        var price       =   8.0
    }

    struct PadThai: Nutrition {
        var calories    =   110.0
        var price       =   8.50
    }
```

Next, I am creating a struct `Individual` which has one method using a generic type:

```
struct Individual {

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    init(fName: String, lName: String)
    {
        firstName   =   fName
        lastName    =   lName
    }

    func eat<T: Nutrition>(food: T) -> T {
        return food
    }
```

When I'm doing like following:

```
let array: [Nutrition] = [Individual(fName: "A", lName: "AAA").eat(Hamburger),Individual(fName: "B", lName: "BBB").eat(PadThai)]
```

the compiler keeps complaining:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I'm also looking at other posts regarding to this error but still can not find a solution. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: You're trying to pass a type into something that expects an instance of that type

Comment: Side note: it's Swift convention to use full words in identifiers. `firstName` and `lastName` would be preferable to parameter names `fName` and `lName`. Why are they inconsistent with the struct member names?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: The reason I named fName and lName is because I wanted to make it simple.However, you are right, the names should be consistent for more clarification and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array expects instances rather than the type themselves:

```
let array: [Nutrition] = [
    Individual(fName: "A", lName: "AAA").eat(Hamburger()),
    Individual(fName: "B", lName: "BBB").eat(PadThai())
]
```